# :app:preDexDebug ... The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android

*Please* do not mark this questions as a duplicate - I have diligently searched SO for a satisfactory answer and have found nothing that worked for me.

I downloaded the very latest version of the Android Studio and attempted to install it on two Windows 7 PC's - a laptop and desktop with identical configurations of JRE and JDK. Results:

laptop: can use Android Studio to build/run first Hello World app; everything seems fine.

desktop: Hello World builds successfully, but will not run. Reports gradle error:

```
 :app:preDexDebug
 The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have spent 3 days now researching this error on SO and elsewhere and have tried everything suggested (edit dx.bat, edit find.java.bat, JAVA_PATH, gradlew --stop etc) but nothing works for me.

Configuration:
    - Android SDK Tools          24.0.1
    - Android SDK Platform Tools 21
    - Android SDK Build Tools    21.1.2

I am on the verge of giving up on my desktop installation of Android Studio.

Any **new** suggestions?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with an error in your Gradle build process. You'll need to clean the project and rebuild to fix this. An easy way to do this is from the root folder of your project run `./gradlew clean`

Comment: Many thanks AggieDev; I tried your suggestion but the error persisted :-(.